# How to document a JSON request body schema in tapir endpoint definition

Tags: scala, documentation, circe, redoc, tapir

I'm using tapir to define a series of endpoints, as follows:

```
    def thingModifyState[M: Encoder: Decoder: Schema] =
      endpoint.put
      .name(s"Modify state of a $name Thing")
      .description("Apply a modification object to a Thing")
      .in("state")
      .in(this.name.description("Type of Thing"))
      .in(
        path[String Refined And[MatchesRegex["^[a-z0-9_]+$"], MaxSize[64]]]
          .description("Name of Thing")
          .name("thing")
      )
      .in(jsonBody[M].description("Object describing modification"))
      .errorOut(
        statusCode
          .description(StatusCode(404), "Thing does not exist")
      )
      .tag(name)
```

`thingModifyState` is then used to define multiple endpoints:

```
blueRoutes.thingModifyState[things.models.blue.StateChange]
redRoutes.thingModifyState[things.models.red.StateChange]
```

The `blue.StateChange` object is defined like this:

```
object StateChange {
  implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames
  implicit val thingStateEncoder: Encoder[StateChange] = deriveEncoder(derivation.renaming.snakeCase)
  implicit val thingStateDecoder: Decoder[StateChange] = deriveDecoder(derivation.renaming.snakeCase)
  implicit val thingStateSchema: Schema[StateChange] = Schema.derived
}

/**
  * Specifies a change to the Thing's state
  *
  * @param counterChange negative or positive increment of the counter
  * @param resetTimestamp new timestamp value
  */
case class StateChange(counterChange: Long, resetTimestamp: Long)
```

When docs are generated (using redoc), the 'request body schema' section looks like this:

[image: screenshot of redoc docs for 'request body schema']

The overall description ("Object describing modification") of the jsonBody is visible in the docs, but I'd like to include descriptions of the jsonBody fields (counter_change / reset_timestamp) as well as their types.

I wouldn't expect the scaladoc definitions from `StateChange` to get picked up, but right now I cannot figure out what to do to get descriptions of the jsonBody fields into the output documentation. Do I need to derive the Schema manually, and include the descriptions somehow?

EDIT: I suspect this: https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/issues/247 of being relevant, but the documentation link at the end of the issue (https://tapir-scala.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoint/customtypes.html#customising-derived-schemas) links to an anchor that is no longer there. I haven't yet found its new location!

EDIT2: Ah, maybe the link is now here: https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/schemas.html#customising-derived-schemas. It mentions using @description annotations, but is missing explanation/examples of where those annotations go for derived schemas.

EDIT3: I was hoping for something like this:

```
import sttp.tapir.EndpointIO.annotations.description

case class StateChange(
  @description("negative or positive increment of the counter") counterChange: Long, 
  @description("new timestamp value") resetTimestamp: Long
)
```

... but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation here: https://tapir.softwaremill.com/en/latest/endpoint/schemas.html#customising-derived-schemas, define the case class like this:

```
import sttp.tapir.Schema.annotations._

case class StateChange(
                        @description("negative or positive increment of the counter") counterChange: Long,
                        @description("new value for reset timestamp") resetTimestamp: Long
                      )
```

Note that you need to import the annotation from `sttp.tapir.Schema.annotations`, not from the location referred to in my question.